# Change Div Width Along on load and resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote this code to change width and height of the wrapper box based on the available space on the screen. When I open the page, div loads well but when I resize it the size of the div does not change.

```js
var width = (($(window).width()) - 100);
var height = (($(window).height()) - 100);

$(window).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper").width(width);
    $("#wrapper").height(height);
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#wrapper").width(width);
    $("#wrapper").height(height);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Xyz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        asd
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you thought of using media queries or relative units in CSS? (VH, VW, %, em)

Comment: Flexbox is also an option, though not universally supported yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recalculate the dimension.

```
$( window ).resize(function(){
    width = (($(window).width())-100);
    height = (($(window).height())-100);
    $("#wrapper").width( width );
    $("#wrapper").height( height );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to recalculate the `height` and `width` variables within the event handlers:

```
$(window).ready(calculateSize);    
$(window).resize(calculateSize);

function calculateSize() {
    var width = $(window).width() - 100;
    var height = $(window).height() - 100;
    $("#wrapper").width(width);
    $("#wrapper").height(height);
}
```

Note however, that this is possible in CSS alone:

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function I wrote and it is working well:

```
//when I load the page
window.onload = function(event) { resizeDiv(); }
//when I resize the page
window.onresize = function(event) { resizeDiv(); }

function resizeDiv() {
    vpw = $(window).width()-100; 
    vph = $(window).height()-100;

    $('#wrapper').css({'height': vph + 'px'});
    $('#wrapper').css({'width': vpw + 'px'});   
}
```